# Using Native File System API to save file to a specific location without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, native-file-system-api-js

I have my own custom system that needs to create *txt* files in order to print cash receipts when there is a new order. I need those files to be saved locally to the computer to a specific location, but is there a way to save the file to that location without prompting the user to choose the file location? Is it possible if you create your own **FileSystemFileHandle** class and then pass it as a **handle**?

```
$('.save').click(function() {
    saveToFile('from website');
});

async function saveToFile(content) {
    const opts = {
        type: 'save-file',
        accepts: [
            {
                description: 'Text File',
                extension: ['txt'],
                mimeType: ['text/plain'],
            }
        ]
    }

    const handle = await window.chooseFileSystemEntries(opts); // don't to that
    // create custom FileSystemFileHandle and point to the file location?
    const handle = FileSystemFileHandle;
    const writable = await handle.createWritable();
    await writable.write(content);
    await writable.close();
}
```

Comment: For security reasons browsers don't allow this, no matter what you try.

Comment: Store your files to LocalStorage.

Comment: @Keith, I guess this can't be done, but I wanted to ask anyway :)

Comment: After user chooses the location once, how can one save the `handle` and persist/restore it 1. between page reloads 2. between browser restarts ? (not sure if 2. is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with the File System Access API, but ironically automatically triggered downloads are still a thing with the `<a download>` approach.

```js
const a = document.createElement('a');
// undefined
a.download = 'example.txt';
// "example.txt"
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(['yolo'], {type : 'text/plain'}));
// "blob:https://example.com/8d494f54-499d-4f32-bdb4-ff047e8c60af"
a.click();
// undefined

// Downloads a file `example.txt` to your Downloads folder
```

Comment: Yes, i use that method + Chrome extension called Download Router and it is working great :)

Comment: Can it be done now? looking at websites like vscode.dev, it clearly seems possible.

Comment: If you persist a `FileSystemDirectoryHandle` to IDB at the correct location that you choose once manually and where you regrant `readwrite` access, then it can be done.